# How can I input PHP type as parameters when type casting from a type to another?

Tags: php

I have these codes:

```
$limit          = (int)    $request->input('limit');
$offset         = (int)    $request->input('offset');
$page           = (int)    $request->input('page');
$orderBy        = (string) $request->input('order_by');
$orderDirection = (string) $request->input('order_direction');
$filters        = (string) $request->input('filters');
```

I want to have function that systematically assign and cast the value. For example:

```
function castValues($myArray)
{
    $urlQueryParams = [];
    foreach ($myArray as $value => $type
    {
        $urlQueryParams[$value] = ($type) $request->input($value);
    }

    return $urlQueryParams;
}

$params = $this->castValues(['limit' => int, 'offset' => 'int', ...]);
```

How can I assign `$type` as it is the data type (`int`, `string`, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `settype`

```
$request = ['limit' => '324', 'offset' => '34'];
function castValues($myArray) {
    global $request;

    $urlQueryParams = [];
    foreach ($myArray as $key => $type) {
        settype($request[$key], $type);
        $urlQueryParams[$key] = $request[$key];
    }

    return $urlQueryParams;
} 

$params = castValues(['limit' => 'int', 'offset' => 'int']);
var_dump($params);
```

**Output** :

```
array(2) { ["limit"]=> int(324) ["offset"]=> int(34) }
```